# Can you wrap each Knex migration with specific SQL code?

Tags: knex.js

I want to preface each migration with a constant `SET ROLE` SQL command but I wasn't seeing anything in the docs that would enable such a thing.

Is there any way to do that?

For example if Knex would regularly spit out:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

it would instead spit out:

```
SET ROLE 'example_user';
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is built upon Abed's answer but utilizes the critical `afterCreate` function. This POC works by using that `afterCreate` hook to run `SET ROLE postgres` after the creation of each new connection.

```
const knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: 'postgres://migration_user:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres',  
  searchPath: ['knex', 'public'],
  pool: {
    afterCreate: function (conn, done) {
      // in this example we use pg driver's connection API
      conn.query('SET role postgres;', function (err) {
        done(err, conn);
      });
    }
  }
});

return knex.migrate.latest()
  .then(function(value) {
    console.log('done')
    return value;
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `raw` knex function, for example, you can run any raw function before your migration as

```js
exports.up = async function (knex) {
    await knex.raw('SELECT 1');
    await knex.raw("SET ROLE 'example_user'");
    await knex.schema.createTable(...)
};

exports.down = function (knex) {
    knex.schema.dropTable(...)
};
```

Comment: Thanks!

Maybe this wasn't clear, but I wanted to know if there's a way it could automatically prepend `SET ROLE 'example_user'` without it having to be in each migration. More like a project-wide configuration

Comment: I don't think there's something for that, but what I'd recommend for your case is:
 rather than applying the migration using `knex migrate:latest` you can programmatically apply it using `knex.migrate.latest()`; and you can prepend that operation with a `knex.raw("SET ROLE 'example_user'");`

Comment: would the `SET ROLE example_user` hold for each of the following migrations ran via `knex.migrate.latest()`? I.e. is it all one and the same postgres connection?

Comment: yes, it would be for the same connection made, or you can use it in `afterCreate` config in knex, which allows you to run an SQL command after a pool connection have been acquired, but be careful of using that, because it will be set for the knex instance you're using in your app, unless you make a seperate knex instace for migrations.